# disable and enable textbox on checkbox click in table

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

i have table populated with data then i add checkbox and textbox into it. below is my code:

```
int count1 = 0;
        TableCell tc;
        foreach (TableRow tr in Resource_TBL.Rows)
        {
            tr.Cells.Add(tc = new TableCell());
            CheckBox cbox = new CheckBox();
            cbox.ID = ""+count1;
            cbox.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('textbox_" + count1 + "').disabled=this.checked;");
            tc.Controls.Add(cbox);

            tr.Cells.Add(tc = new TableCell());
            TextBox tbox = new TextBox();
            tbox.ID = "textbox_" + count1;
            tbox.CssClass = "form-control";
            tbox.Enabled = false;
            tbox.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Enter Detail Here");
            count1 += 1;
            tc.Controls.Add(tbox);
        }
```

i have tried :

```
cbox.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('textbox_" + count1 + "').Enabled=this.checked;");
```

but its not working. have an error saying(Unable to set property 'Enabled' of undefined or null reference)

is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: Can you try this

    cbox.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert(document.getElementById('textbox_" + count1 + "'));");

Insted of cbox.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('textbox_" + count1 + "').Enabled=this.checked;");. and please comment the output.

Comment: @Dinesh Patra. nothing happen

Comment: is it throwing any error??

Comment: @Dinesh Patra nope. nothing happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an "Enabled" property for the textbox simply because its name is in Pascal-case. :)

```
cbox.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('textbox_" + count1 + "').disabled = !this.checked;");
```

Comment: i got error JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'disabled' of undefined or null reference

Comment: @HJK So it means the textbox by the ID does not exist. You may have to check the output HTML first to see the proper ID.

Comment: If I remembered correctly, the asp.net seems add some kind of suffix behind the control ID it generated.

Comment: thanks.. i saved me!! the code adding the id get MainContent_textbox_

Answer (score 0):

i think your id is false
I advice you using jquery it is syntaxicly shorter and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count1 = 0;
        TableCell tc;
        foreach (TableRow tr in Resource_TBL.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox cbox = new CheckBox();
            cbox.ID = ""+count1;
            TextBox tbox = new TextBox();
            tbox.ID = "textbox_" + count1;
            tbox.CssClass = "form-control";
            tbox.Enabled = false;
            tbox.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Enter Detail Here");
            count1 += 1;
            cbox.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('" + tbox.ClientID + "').disabled=!this.checked;");
            tr.Cells.Add(tc = new TableCell());
            tc.Controls.Add(cbox);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc = new TableCell());
            tc.Controls.Add(tbox);
        }
```

Its all about the order. don't manually use the ID because when you use masterpage or other controls then the ID will change on the page itself. Use ClientID to know what the ID of the control is on the page.

Create controls first. then add them to your table hierachy later.
Also you might want to put a ! before this.checked. else your textbox will be disabled as soon your checkbox gets selected.